# Call function in child component from the parent component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I have a child component inside my parent component as below:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.articolo.items}" var="item">
    <c:RigaTabellaItemsKit item="{!item}" PicklistStatoKit_SelVal="{!v.PicklistStatoKit_SelVal}" aura:id="item_in_kit"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

During some operation inside the `Helper` of the parent component, I should call a function defined inside the child component.

**Helper (Parent):**

```
var pesi_value = component.get("v.pesi");
var articoloKit = component.get("v.articolo");
var itemsInKit = articoloKit.items;
var value1 = 2.0;

for (var i = 0; i < pesi_value.length; i++){
    itemsInKit[i].voce.Prezzo_totale__c = value1 * pesi_value[i];
    //here I should call a function inside the child component.
}
```

Assume that the function which I want to call is as described inside the `Helper` of the child as below:

```
calcolaRicarico : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.calcolaRicarico(component, event);
}
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can call using `aura:method` by using **`aura:id`**

```
<c:RigaTabellaItemsKit  aura:id="item_in_kit"/>
```

**Helper (Parent):**

```
cmp.find("item_in_kit").calcolaRicarico();
```

**In child:**

```
<aura:method name="calcolaRicarico" action="{!c.calcolaRicarico}" />
```

Comment: I added the line you mentioned to the child. and in my parent (helper) I called component.find("item_in_kit").calcolaRicarico(); But it gave me error that this function does not exist.

Comment: Did you handled <aura:method>in child component .As you mentioned you want to call child helper method... you need to call helper method from child controller.

Comment: Yes the method is already defined if you meant defining it by handling

Comment: Nope.I meant to define a method in child component. for parent component to call a method on a child component ..

Comment: Yep, it is defined already.

Comment: @reshad you cannot directly call an child component's helper method, you need called it via controller method in the child. In other words, you will call the aura:method of the child from the parent, which in turn calls the child's helper.

Comment: @vignesh did you figure out the solution