# Calling javascript methods

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have 2 components.

- Component 1 contains `method1`,
- Component 2 contains `method2`.

My question is : At the time of method2 call in component2. In method2, I have to call method1 is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Events to call.

**Eg:**  `component1` contains `method1` that fire the event and it can handled by `component2` and  you can call `method2` by handler . go through with [Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_intro.htm)

there ara several event type **eg**

**1.APPLICATION EVENT**

If your components have no communication you can go with **Application Event**

```
  <aura:Application >
       <c:component1 />
       <c:component2 />
    </aura:Application>
```

- (In short because of using application event there is no communication between components).In these scenerio you can go with `Application Event` go through this link for [Application Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application.htm)

**2.Component Event:**

**component1:**

```
<aura:component>
  <c:component2 />
</aura:component>
```

If  `component2` fires the event it can be handled by `component 2` as well as `component 1` you can call methods by handler.Always try to use component event as possible because it is comunincationg within the components.its a best practice too.

**3.Aura:method**

If you want to call `parent component`  to `child component` method best approach use `<aura: method>`

visit the link [aura:method example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156214/call-function-in-child-component-from-the-parent-component/156243#156243)